# stop words removal not working correctly

Tags: python, regex, string, split, stop-words

Any idea why stop words removing is not working correctly? It is replacing stuff wrongly and sometimes replaces say a with an or can't consider `it's` as a single word.

```
stop_words=open("stopwords.txt")
stop_words=stop_words.read().split("\n")
print stop_words
for line in splitted_tweets:
    #print line
    #print "***************************************"
    if (line.__contains__("text='")):
        start_index=line.index("text='")+6
        end_index=line.index("',", start_index)
        tweet=line[start_index:end_index]
        print tweet
        print "**********"
        tweet_words = re.sub("[^\w]", " " , tweet).split()
        print tweet_words
        for word in stop_words:
                if word in tweet_words:
                        print word
                        tweet=tweet.replace(word, "")

        print "?????????????????????????"
        print tweet
```

Here's some example output:

```
['RT', 'sayingsforgirls', 'Do', 'not', 'touch', 'MY', 'iPhone', 'It', 's', 'not', 'an', 'usPhone', 'it', 's', 'not', 'a', 'wePhone', 'it', 's', 'not', 'an', 'ourPhone', 'it', 's', 'an', 'iPhone']
a
an
it
not
?????????????????????????
RT @syingsforgirls: Do  touch MY iPhone. It's  n usPhone, 's   wePhone, 's  n ourPhone, 's n iPhone.
Do not touch MY iPhone. It's not an usPhone, it's not a wePhone, it's not an ourPhone, it's an iPhone.
**********
['Do', 'not', 'touch', 'MY', 'iPhone', 'It', 's', 'not', 'an', 'usPhone', 'it', 's', 'not', 'a', 'wePhone', 'it', 's', 'not', 'an', 'ourPhone', 'it', 's', 'an', 'iPhone']
a
an
it
not
?????????????????????????
Do  touch MY iPhone. It's  n usPhone, 's   wePhone, 's  n ourPhone, 's n iPhone.
RT @BrianaaSymonee: she says imma dog, but it takes one to know one...
**********
['RT', 'BrianaaSymonee', 'she', 'says', 'imma', 'dog', 'but', 'it', 'takes', 'one', 'to', 'know', 'one']
but
it
she
to
?????????????????????????
RT @BrianaaSymonee:  says imma dog,   takes one  know one...
she says imma dog, but it takes one to know one...
**********
```

Comment: Slightly O/T, but `line.__contains__("text='")` would normally be written `"text='" in line`.

Comment: thanks but that line is working!

Comment: ...I didn't say it wasn't, but it makes your code much easier to read, follow and debug if you follow the conventions of the language you're using. Have a look at https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ and cut this down to a [mcve]. What output were you expecting?

Comment: I'm with @jonrsharpe. If you want to get a proper answer you need to explain that what's the problem exactly.

Comment: @Kasramvd if you look at the question I have mentioned for words like "it's" it is splitting it into 'It', 's', which is not correct. I want it to be only one word.

Comment: @MonaJalal So you could just asked about that specific problem. Anyway, that's because of that you are replacing all none word characters with space which will include one quotation. if you wan't to split your text to chunks of words you can use `re.findall(r"\b[\w']+\b",test_string)` which will returns a list of all the words contain quotation as well.

Comment: `>>> re.findall(r"\b[\w']+\b",s)
['Do', 'not', 'touch', 'MY', 'iPhone', "It's", 'not', 'an', 'usPhone', "it's", 'not', 'a', 'wePhone', "it's", 'not', 'an', 'ourPhone', "it's", 'an', 'iPhone']`

Comment: the line `tweet_words = re.sub("[^\w]", " " , tweet).split()` replaces anything thats not a word char with a space. `'` is not a word character.